# How do I index/optimize this query on postgres involving group by?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a query of a table of ~3 million rows like so:

```
select 
city, 
state, 
avg(latitude as float) as latitude, 
avg(longitude as float)as longitude, 
count(latitude) as num_trees 
from public.standard_dataset 
group by city, state
```

and I have created the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX get_cities ON public.standard_dataset (state, city, latitude, longitude);
```

But the query hasn't improved at all (~4 seconds). This is my first time learning about indices so any help is much appreciated

EDIT: Here is my execution plan:

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=69162.87..69640.68 rows=1748 width=41)
  Group Key: city, state
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=69162.87..69570.76 rows=3496 width=89)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=68162.84..68167.21 rows=1748 width=89)
              Sort Key: city, state
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=68051.22..68068.70 rows=1748 width=89)
                    Group Key: city, state
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on standard_dataset  (cost=0.00..51414.43 rows=1330943 width=33)
```

Comment: The index should have the columns in the same order as your grouping.

Comment: TY but it didnt really make a difference

Comment: Oh, wait, you probably would need to start with `latitude` and `longitude` that you are filtering for. However, how selective is your filter condition? If all of the trees have coordinates anyway, postgres will need to go through the entire table in any case, and there's no use of an index for that. Scanning 3 million rows just takes some seconds…

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: That execution plan doesn't match the query (where is the filter for the `WHERE` conditions?).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry about that - I did end up removing the where condition because it actually isn't needed.

Comment: I have got to wonder why you are averaging longitudes and latitudes? Are you attempting to fine the Centroid of a shape or set of points of the earth's surface.  If so then just computing the average does not work, unless it is a very small regular area. You need to build a geometry and then use one of the PostGis  Centroid  functions. You may want to see [PostGis developers guide](https://postgis.net/docs/_. This requires the PostGis extension.

Comment: I think centroids is definitely where I'm trying to go. Will this perform faster than avg?

Comment: If you are retrieving all rows, no index will help and a Seq Scan is the most efficient way to do that. Maybe your group by spills to disk, but that can only be seen in a plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** not in the "simple" explain you provided.

Comment: If the centroid is what you need, then it does not matter whether avg is faster (my guess the centroid calculation is slower - but I have never averaged lat/long). But the calculation will be correct. A slower query that produces the correct result is far **far** superior to an extremely fast query that produces the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are scanning the whole table, an index could only be useful for an index-only scan. Such an index would have to contain all columns used in the query.

Other than that, a sequential scan is the most efficient access method.